# Performance comparison of modulo operator and bitwise AND

Tags: java, performance, bit-manipulation, jmh

I'm working to determine if an 32bit integer is even or odd. I have setup 2 approaches:

modulo(%) approach

```
int r = (i % 2);
```

bitwise(&) approach

```
int r = (i & 0x1);
```

Both approaches work successfully. So I run each line for 15000 times to test performance.

Result:

modulo(%) approach ([source code](https://github.com/kflau/modulo-division-vs-bitwise-benchmark/blob/master/src/test/java/com/aei/bit/modulo/benchmark/ModulusTest.java))

mean 141.5801887ns | SD 270.0700275ns

bitwise(&) approach ([source code](https://github.com/kflau/modulo-division-vs-bitwise-benchmark/blob/master/src/test/java/com/aei/bit/modulo/benchmark/BitwiseModulusTest.java))

mean 141.2504ns | SD 193.6351007ns

**Questions**:

Why is bitwise(&) more stable than division(%) ?

Does JVM optimize modulo(%) using AND(&) according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393373/performance-wise-how-fast-are-bitwise-operator-vs-normal-modulus?answertab=oldest#tab-top)?

Comment: Your two benchmarks look almost identical to me, minus a slightly different standard deviation.  But, there is a chance that you did not even setup both tests in a statistically meaningful way.

Comment: First first link should probably be https://github.com/kflau/modulo-division-vs-bitwise-benchmark/blob/master/src/test/java/com/aei/bit/modulo/benchmark/ModulusTest.java instead.

Comment: Relevant anyway: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: You're doing it completely wrong. You can't use nanoTime() to measure a single operation execution, since it usually has granularity of hunder of nanoseconds or even more (depending on your OS). Use JMH and check an assembly code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's try to reproduce with JMH.

```
@Benchmark
@Measurement(timeUnit = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
public int first() throws IOException {
    return i % 2;
}

@Benchmark
@Measurement(timeUnit = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
public int second() throws IOException {
    return i & 0x1;
}
```

Okay, it is reproducable. The `first` is slightly slower than the `second`. Now let's figure out why. Run it with `-prof perfnorm`:

```
Benchmark                                 Mode  Cnt   Score    Error  Units
MyBenchmark.first                         avgt   50   2.674 ±  0.028  ns/op
MyBenchmark.first:CPI                     avgt   10   0.301 ±  0.002   #/op
MyBenchmark.first:L1-dcache-load-misses   avgt   10   0.001 ±  0.001   #/op
MyBenchmark.first:L1-dcache-loads         avgt   10  11.011 ±  0.146   #/op
MyBenchmark.first:L1-dcache-stores        avgt   10   3.011 ±  0.034   #/op
MyBenchmark.first:L1-icache-load-misses   avgt   10  ≈ 10⁻³            #/op
MyBenchmark.first:LLC-load-misses         avgt   10  ≈ 10⁻⁴            #/op
MyBenchmark.first:LLC-loads               avgt   10  ≈ 10⁻⁴            #/op
MyBenchmark.first:LLC-store-misses        avgt   10  ≈ 10⁻⁵            #/op
MyBenchmark.first:LLC-stores              avgt   10  ≈ 10⁻⁴            #/op
MyBenchmark.first:branch-misses           avgt   10  ≈ 10⁻⁴            #/op
MyBenchmark.first:branches                avgt   10   4.006 ±  0.054   #/op
MyBenchmark.first:cycles                  avgt   10   9.322 ±  0.113   #/op
MyBenchmark.first:dTLB-load-misses        avgt   10  ≈ 10⁻⁴            #/op
MyBenchmark.first:dTLB-loads              avgt   10  10.939 ±  0.175   #/op
MyBenchmark.first:dTLB-store-misses       avgt   10  ≈ 10⁻⁵            #/op
MyBenchmark.first:dTLB-stores             avgt   10   2.991 ±  0.045   #/op
MyBenchmark.first:iTLB-load-misses        avgt   10  ≈ 10⁻⁵            #/op
MyBenchmark.first:iTLB-loads              avgt   10  ≈ 10⁻⁴            #/op
MyBenchmark.first:instructions            avgt   10  30.991 ±  0.427   #/op
MyBenchmark.second                        avgt   50   2.263 ±  0.015  ns/op
MyBenchmark.second:CPI                    avgt   10   0.320 ±  0.001   #/op
MyBenchmark.second:L1-dcache-load-misses  avgt   10   0.001 ±  0.001   #/op
MyBenchmark.second:L1-dcache-loads        avgt   10  11.045 ±  0.152   #/op
MyBenchmark.second:L1-dcache-stores       avgt   10   3.014 ±  0.032   #/op
MyBenchmark.second:L1-icache-load-misses  avgt   10  ≈ 10⁻³            #/op
MyBenchmark.second:LLC-load-misses        avgt   10  ≈ 10⁻⁴            #/op
MyBenchmark.second:LLC-loads              avgt   10  ≈ 10⁻⁴            #/op
MyBenchmark.second:LLC-store-misses       avgt   10  ≈ 10⁻⁵            #/op
MyBenchmark.second:LLC-stores             avgt   10  ≈ 10⁻⁴            #/op
MyBenchmark.second:branch-misses          avgt   10  ≈ 10⁻⁴            #/op
MyBenchmark.second:branches               avgt   10   4.014 ±  0.045   #/op
MyBenchmark.second:cycles                 avgt   10   8.024 ±  0.098   #/op
MyBenchmark.second:dTLB-load-misses       avgt   10  ≈ 10⁻⁵            #/op
MyBenchmark.second:dTLB-loads             avgt   10  10.989 ±  0.161   #/op
MyBenchmark.second:dTLB-store-misses      avgt   10  ≈ 10⁻⁶            #/op
MyBenchmark.second:dTLB-stores            avgt   10   3.004 ±  0.042   #/op
MyBenchmark.second:iTLB-load-misses       avgt   10  ≈ 10⁻⁵            #/op
MyBenchmark.second:iTLB-loads             avgt   10  ≈ 10⁻⁵            #/op
MyBenchmark.second:instructions           avgt   10  25.076 ±  0.296   #/op
```

Note the difference in cycles and instructions. And now that's kind of obvious. The `first` does care about the sign, but the `second` does not (just bitwise and). To make sure this is the reason take a look at the assembly fragment:

***first:***

```
0x00007f91111f8355: mov     0xc(%r10),%r11d   ;*getfield i
0x00007f91111f8359: mov     %r11d,%edx
0x00007f91111f835c: and     $0x1,%edx
0x00007f91111f835f: mov     %edx,%r10d
0x00007f6bd120a6e2: neg     %r10d
0x00007f6bd120a6e5: test    %r11d,%r11d
0x00007f6bd120a6e8: cmovl   %r10d,%edx
```

***second:***

```
0x00007ff36cbda580: mov     $0x1,%edx
0x00007ff36cbda585: mov     0x40(%rsp),%r10
0x00007ff36cbda58a: and     0xc(%r10),%edx
```

Comment: I'm missing here an explanation like "modulus is a terribly slow operation, but the JVM optimizes `i % 2` as `i > 0 ? i & 1 : -(i & 1)`.

Comment: @maaartinus This is true Iff `i` is a power of 2. Otherwise it compiles to some heavier bit-manipulations (surprisingly, not simple `idiv` as I expected).

Answer (score 1):

An execution time of 150 ns is about 500 clock cycles. I don't think there has ever been a processor that went about the business of checking a bit this inefficiently :-).

The problem is that your test harness is flawed in many ways. In particular:

- you make no attempt to trigger JIT compilation before starting the clock
- System.nanotime() is not guaranteed to have nanosecond accuracy
- System.nanotime() is quite a bit more expensive to call that the code you want to measure

See [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) for a more complete list of things to keep in mind.

Here's a better benchmark:

```
public abstract class Benchmark {

    final String name;

    public Benchmark(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + "\t" + time() + " ns / iteration";
    }

    private BigDecimal time() {
        try {
            // automatically detect a reasonable iteration count (and trigger just in time compilation of the code under test)
            int iterations;
            long duration = 0;
            for (iterations = 1; iterations < 1_000_000_000 && duration < 1_000_000_000; iterations *= 2) {
                long start = System.nanoTime();
                run(iterations);
                duration = System.nanoTime() - start;
                cleanup();
            }
            return new BigDecimal((duration) * 1000 / iterations).movePointLeft(3);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Executes the code under test.
     * @param iterations
     *            number of iterations to perform
     * @return any value that requires the entire code to be executed (to
     *         prevent dead code elimination by the just in time compiler)
     * @throws Throwable
     *             if the test could not complete successfully
     */
    protected abstract Object run(int iterations) throws Throwable;

    /**
     * Cleans up after a run, setting the stage for the next.
     */
    protected void cleanup() {
        // do nothing
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(new Benchmark("%") {
            @Override
            protected Object run(int iterations) throws Throwable {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
                    sum += i % 2;
                }
                return sum; 
            }
        });
        System.out.println(new Benchmark("&") {
            @Override
            protected Object run(int iterations) throws Throwable {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
                    sum += i & 1;
                }
                return sum;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

On my machine, it prints:

```
%   0.375 ns / iteration
&   0.139 ns / iteration
```

So the difference is, as expected, on the order of a couple clock cycles. That is, `& 1` was optimized slightly better by this JIT on this particular hardware, but the difference is so small it is extremely unlikely to have a measurable (let alone significant) impact on the performance of your program.

Answer (score 0):

The two operations correspond to different JVM processor instructions:

```
irem     // int remainder (%)
iand     // bitwise and (&)
```

Somewhere I read `irem` is usually implemented by the JVM, while `iand` is available on hardware. [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se10/html/jvms-6.html) explains the two instructions as follows:

`iand`

> An int result is calculated by taking the bitwise AND (conjunction) of value1 and value2.

`irem`

> The int result is value1 - (value1 / value2) * value2.

It seems reasonable to me to assume that `iand` results in less CPU cycles.

Comment: Most CPUs can compute reminder, too, but it's slow and the JVM [optimizes it to AND if possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51232809/performance-comparison-of-modulo-operator-and-bitwise-and#comment89772081_51233271).

Comment: @maaartinus When does this optimization take place?

Comment: Practically, all optimizations take place at runtime. `javac` (or `ecj` or whatever) doesn't care. The JVM does. Many optimizations lead to a code bloat and it's much better to concentrate on the hot spots (and so they call [their  compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot)). Moreover, many optimizations are based on some assumptions, which may get invalidated later and the JVM must [deoptimize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20542675/581205). Therefore you see nothing like that in the bytecode.