# Why doesnt JIT compiler ( Java ) save the results?

Tags: java, jit

As I studied about JIT compiler from here:
[What does a just-in-time (JIT) compiler do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95635/what-does-a-just-in-time-jit-compiler-do)
and

> there's no *.exe or *.dll generated by the Java JIT for Windows. It
>   writes the processor instructions to memory (RAM) and runs it from
>   there. There's no need to create a separate PE file with file-headers
>   and everything

My question is **WHY** doesn't JIT compiler ( Java ) save the results? Isn't it useful to store compiled code to save time for the next launch?

(My question is different from the mentioned above, because I emphasized on **WHY**)

Comment: I don't think this is an inherently bad question, but only a developer of an actual JVM would be able to answer for certain. Most likely, it's because saving the internal JVM state would be an extremely tricky operation; that said, check into GraalVM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ouput of a JIT may be different for each run - it can optimize for the current load pattern. This sometimes allows it to optimize more agressively than what would be possible for pre-compiled code that needs to be reusable.

If the load-pattern changes and the optimization is found to be sub-optimal or even adverse, a JIT can de-optimize and possibly attempt a different optimization

(see also [About the dynamic de-optimization of HotSpot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522870/about-the-dynamic-de-optimization-of-hotspot))

Now, it might sometimes save some performance to keep these results of various compiled versions around and reuse them later, but it would also require a significant amount of book-keeping to be able to find out if a section of code has already been compiled with currently relevant optimizations.

I suppose that is just not considered worth the effort. Its a tradeoff between doing file-IO and usually fast compilation of small sections of code.